# VBA - Undo ComboBox change

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I cannot seem to get this code to work... I am trying to basically say, if the combo box changes and the range is not empty ask if the user really does want to clear the range and make the change. If they say no, then undo the combobox change back to what it was. My options for the Sub do not display a BeforeUpdate, only the Change and some others.

I tried to capture the value beforehand and set it back to that, but it doesnt work.

Any ideas welcome!!

```
Sub ComboBox_UPC_C18_Change()

    Dim ComboBox_UPC_C18_Value As String

    Dim Location As Range
    Set Location = Range("Location_C18")

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Location) = 0 Then

            Exit Sub

        ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want change the UPC (clearing the row's data)?", vbYesNo, "User Confirmation") = vbYes Then

            Location.Value = ""

        ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want change the UPC (clearing the row's data)?", vbYesNo, "User Confirmation") = vbNo Then

            ComboBox_UPC_C18.Value = ComboBox_UPC_C18_Value
            MsgBox (ComboBox_UPC_C18_Value)

            Exit Sub

        End If

    ComboBox_UPC_C18_Value = ComboBox_UPC_C18.Value
    MsgBox (ComboBox_UPC_C18_Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test this but I think this is close to what you are looking for.  Let me know if I am totally off base here:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_UPC_C18_Change()
    Dim RngLocation     As Range
    Dim PrevLocation    As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    PrevLocation = Range("Location_C18").Value

    If PrevLocation = "" Then
        Range("Location_C18").Value = ComboBox_UPC_C18.Value
    Else
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change this?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Range("Location_C18").Value = ComboBox_UPC_C18.Value
        Else
            ComboBox_UPC_C18.Value = PrevLocation
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Stew! Thank you so much for your response. This might be close, but let me explain more about what I am trying to do: The combo box is to select a material. The cells in range Location_C18 tell how much of each material is located in that space (warehouse management) ... The location C18 can only hold one type of material, so if the user decides to change it, they must verify, because it will clear the cells; but if they say no, I actually dont want to change it, the combobox should not change, it should display the material value that was there before they tried to change it.

Comment: The problem I run into is if they try to change the combobox to Material B (previously Material A) when they say "No" on the msgbox prompt, the number of materials doesnt change (which is good) but the combobox stays on Material B, when it should have reverted back to Material A.

Comment: Okay, I think I am starting to follow.  Is the ComboBox an ActiveX object?

Comment: And it sounds like the range you are working with to get the material counts is contingent on the selection made within the ComboBox right?

Comment: Hey stew- it is an ActiveX object. And yes, the range is contingent on the selection of that combobox. I appreciate your follow up!